# Code does not pass `gsmAccess.begin(PINNUMBER)==GSM_READY)`

Tags: gsm

I am not able to get my code to pass

> if(gsmAccess.begin(PINNUMBER)==GSM_READY) {

I have modified the PIN number on my sim card to be `0000`, and yet its stuck on `begin`.

How do I prepare the SIM CARD to pass the begin

Comment: This has been abandoned for months without information sufficient to make it answerable ever being provided.  Voting to close as unclear.

Comment: Closing needs a better reason, not a vendetta.

Comment: That your problem is insufficiently specified is a valid reason.  Otherwise, edit your question to make it answerable.  Post the code of the method where it gets stuck, and add logging to determine where exactly that happens.

Comment: This would be an acceptable question if it had a bare minimum sketch (enough code that we could run it on our own Arduinos and reproduce the issue). Feel free to edit. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting the SIM card into a mobile phone in case it hasn't been initialised by your provider. Set up the PIN for the card using the settings on the phone, see the manual for instructions on how to do this.

Now you can use the PIN you entered on the phone to unlock the SIM in your code.

Comment: Tried it, did not work.